# Why does the password for a zip-file not work?

Tags: password, archive, zip

I've tried to unpack a password-protected zip-file on Ubuntu 14.04. Although I am absolutely sure the password I use is correct the built-in unzip-function gives an "unknown error".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Install 7zip via your package manager or type

```
sudo apt-get install p7zip
```

in your terminal. Then try it again.

Comment: In my case, it was `p7zip-full`